# Как увеличить производительность нейросети yolov8

Tags: python, pytorch, deep-learning

Я читал что для этого можно использовать cuda ядра но у меня нет nvidia видеокарты(только radeon rx 580 pro). Вопрос в том как мне включить использование видеокарты в скрипте программы.Или посоветуйте другие способы увеличения производительности.
Система: mac os catalina

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На данный момент нет полноценного решения по использованию графического ускорителя от AMD (https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/)
Попробуй потренить свою модель в google colab

Comment: будем пробовать